# Delete Directory with java code send an error file already in use by an other process

Tags: java, directory

I am writing a java program to delete a non empty directory after its creation.

When executing it, I got an error saying that the directory is already in use by an other process

I want to know how can I close the file or the process using it in order to delete normaly the directory. This is the code I am using to delete a simple file:

```
FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(new File(properties.getPackagePath() + "/" + enrollType + "." + sslType + ".tar.gz"));
```

And this is the code I am using to delete a full directory:

```
Files.walk(path)
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .map(Path::toFile)
    .forEach(File::delete);
```